# C# Dataset - How to show same record with different dates

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset, record, repeat

I have a table that stores information about some events which are shown on the website. These events repeat every week,so instead of entering the same event for every week I wanted to have the option that the user will just select the checkbox (repeat every week), and then somehow read if the record has this checked show the record with different dates(add seven days). Another problem is that there might be more than two events that will repeat every week. I thought I should handle this on runtime when the page loads or should I handle this when the data is entered? Can someone give me  a direction? When the page loads I'm simply filling the dataset as follows and then just binding the gird to the dataset:

```
        DataSet eventsDS = new DataSet();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [tbl_events]order by [date]", conn);

        SqlDataAdapter daEvents = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        daEvents.Fill(eventsDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is way beyond the capabilities of any mainstream database system. It also introduces a bunch of problems that you probably don't want to deal with. Dealing with those problems would be more trouble than just adding an event to the database for every week.

For example, if you had an event that starts on 2011/01/01 and repeats every week, then your query, `select * from [tbl_events] order by [date]` would produce an infinite result set, starting with 2011/01/01. I suppose you could limit it by supplying a date range, but if you ever forgot an ending value, the query would grind away generating results until you exceeded some limit.

The same kind of thing would happen if you were to write code to do this. Your code would have to put some upper limit on the number of weeks for which you show events.

Your two choices are:

1) Enter one event record in the database for every week, with some kind of upper limit on the number of weeks ahead you add records. You'll also need some way to add more records for the repeated event. For example, perhaps you add 26 events (for 6 months) initially, and then after the event occurs each week, the program automatically adds one for 6 months in the future.

2) Enter one event record that gets updated with the new trigger date each week. Now your problem is in reporting. After query, you have to determine that the record is a repeated event, and then decide how many events you want to show.

The second option becomes a problem if you want to do a range query, because you can't just check the `[date]` field for events in the future. You could store a `begin_date` and `end_date` field, and do the range query against those.

Which method you choose depends in large part on how you're going to use the system. If it's primarily for events that occur one time, then you're probably better off using the first option. If the system is primarily for events that repeat on schedules, then you probably want to use the second option and formalize the concept of starting and ending dates, and repeat frequencies.

Comment: Thanks Jim! I can set a date for an even to end. I'm fine with that. Not sure if you are a C# developer, can someone give me an option in terms of C# code?